# Automator: Open the current PDF file in Preview with another app

Tags: automator, pdf

After I open a PDF file with Preview, I want to open the same file in another PDF viewer (Skim or Adobe Acrobat).  How can Automator do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* that will open in **Skim** the front opened **PDF** *document* in **Preview** from the **Preview** > **Services** *menu*, or a *keyboard shortcut* if assigned in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**.

This **Automator** *Service* was tested and works for me under **macOS High Sierra** assigning it a *keyboard shortcut* of **⌥⌘S**, but should work as a *Quick Action* in **macOS Mojave** and later.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Preview" to ¬
        set pdfDoc to (path of front document)
    tell application "Skim" to open pdfDoc
end run
```

[image: Automator Service Workflow]

---

Here is an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* that will open the same **PDF** *document(s)* in both **Preview** and **Skim** from **Finder**.

In **Finder**, select one or more **PDF** *documents*, or a *folder* full of **PDF** *documents* and then *right-click* and select, e.g., **Open PDF in Preview and Skim** from the **Services** *context menu*.

This **Automator** *Service* was tested and works for me under **macOS High Sierra**, but should work as a *Quick Action* in **macOS Mojave** and later.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Preview" to open input
    tell application "Skim" to open input
end run
```

[image: Automator Service Workflow]

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to open Skim from Preview, not from Finder?

Comment: @Chang, I've updated my answer to accommodate your comment and is in line with your original question. I've left the other **Automator** _Service/Quick Action_ as you may find it useful too.

Comment: I really appreciate it. It works great. One more question. If I want to enable this service in any application, instead of just Preview.app, how can I modify the AppleScript part?

Comment: @Chang, As not all _applications_ use (or expose) the `path` _property_ to show the _path_ of the opened _document_ and some are not directly scriptable, so it would take considerable coding to make it work for any _application_. For example, while you could open the **PDF** _document_ in **Adobe Reader** you could not get the `path` _property_ of that _document_ from **Adobe Reader** to then open it in a different _application_. Not every widget can be a universal widget and sometimes you just have to build a widget to do a specific task.